# asp.net mvc Angular js Datatable not working

Tags: angularjs, razor, angular-datatables

I am new in angular js with datatable and i am getting when on page load, i am trying to add load datatable using angular js.

**Error :**

```
angular.js:138 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module PMS due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angularMoment due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angularMoment' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

**Detail Error**
[Error link](https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.5/docs/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=PMS&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20Failed%20to%20instantiate%20module%20angularMoment%20due%20to%3A%0AError%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20Module%20%27angularMoment%27%20is%20not%20available%21%20You%20either%20misspelled%20the%20module%20name%20or%20forgot%20to%20load%20it.%20If%20registering%20a%20module%20ensure%20that%20you%20specify%20the%20dependencies%20as%20the%20second%20argument.%0A%0Ahttps%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.7.5%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DangularMoment%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520Module%2520%27angularMoment%27%2520is%2520not%2520available%21%2520You%2520either%2520misspelled%2520the%2520module%2520name%2520or%2520forgot%2520to%2520load%2520it.%2520If%2520registering%2520a%2520module%2520ensure%2520that%2520you%2520specify%2520the%2520dependencies%2520as%2520the%2520second%2520argument.%250Ahttps%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.7.5%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DangularMoment%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A61800%252FScripts%252Fangular.js%253A138%253A12%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A61800%252FScripts%252Fangular.js%253A2290%253A17%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520ensure%2520%28http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A61800%252FScripts%252Fangular.js%253A2211%253A38%29%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520module%2520%28http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A61800%252FScripts%252Fangular.js%253A2288%253A14%29%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A61800%252FScripts%252Fangular.js%253A5017%253A22%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520forEach%2520%28http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A61800%252FScripts%252Fangular.js%253A387%253A20%29%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520loadModules%2520%28http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A61800%252FScripts%252Fangular.js%253A5001%253A5%29%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A61800%252FScripts%252Fangular.js%253A5019%253A40%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520forEach%2520%28http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A61800%252FScripts%252Fangular.js%253A387%253A20%29%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520loadModules%2520%28http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A61800%252FScripts%252Fangular.js%253A5001%253A5%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A61800%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A138%3A12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A61800%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A5041%3A15%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20%28http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A61800%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A387%3A20%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20%28http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A61800%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A5001%3A5%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A61800%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A5019%3A40%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20%28http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A61800%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A387%3A20%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20%28http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A61800%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A5001%3A5%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20createInjector%20%28http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A61800%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A4918%3A19%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20doBootstrap%20%28http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A61800%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A1942%3A20%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20bootstrap%20%28http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A61800%2FScripts%2Fangular.js%3A1963%3A12)

**My Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('PMS', ['angularMoment', 'ui.router', 'datatables'])
    .filter('jsonDate', ['$filter', function($filter) {
        return function(input, format) {
            return (input) ? $filter('date')(parseInt(input.substr(6)), format) : '';
        };
    }]);
app.controller('SpaceController', function($scope, SpaceService) {
    $scope.getAll = function() {

        loader(true);
        var getData = SpaceService.getAllData();
        getData.then(function(response) {
            if (response.data.success) {
                $scope.listdt = response.data.data;
                $scope.populateStatus();
                loader(false);
            } else {
                errorAlert("Oops", response.data.message);
                loader(false);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**My Template**

```
@ {
    Layout = null;
} <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link href="~/Scripts/PMS_theme_js/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Content/PMS_theme_css/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body ng-app="PMS" ng-controller="SpaceController">
    <table datatable="ng" class="table display" id="TblID">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Key</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="d in listdt">
                <td>{{d.SpaceID}}</td>
                <td>{{d.SpaceKey}}</td>
                <td>{{d.SpaceName}}</td>
                <td>{{d.SpaceDesc}}</td>
                <td> <span class="label label-table {{d.StatusKey == 'A' ? 'label-success' : 'label-red'}}">{{d.StatusName}}</span></td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="edit(d)"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-click="delete(d)"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="~/Scripts/PMS_theme_js/plugins/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/PMS_theme_js/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-datatables/dist/angular-datatables.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Angular/Module.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Its working fine with Datatable,but when add **datatable** module its start getting error.Any reason where and what i am doing wrong with Angular js datatable.

Comment: It seems that you've not injected `angularMoment` correctly, refer to the [documentation](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment)

Comment: @TusharWalzade,Issue resolved and thank you very much!!

Comment: You may accept/ upvote it as an answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> An error you mentioned shows that you've not injected `angularMoment` correctly, refer to the ***[documentation](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment)***.

Ensure that you've included both **moment.js** and **angular-moment.js** in your application, which would look something like following in your case -

```
<script src="~/Scripts/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-moment/angular-moment.js"></script>
```